# Is there any movie scene about helping a rival to their maximum potential before taking them down?

Tags: trope

I want to find a movie scene about helping a rival to their maximum potential before taking them down. The ultimate concept to be illustrated is the "steelman argument" or "[Rapoport's rules](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Rapoport%27s_Rules)". It's a protocol to compose a successful (and helpful) critical commentary:

> 1. You should attempt to re-express your target's position so clearly, vividly, and fairly that your target says, "Thanks, I wish I’d thought of putting it that way."
> 2. You should list any points of agreement (especially if they are not matters of general or widespread agreement).
> 3. You should mention anything you have learned from your target.
> 4. Only then are you permitted to say so much as a word of rebuttal or criticism.

Any movie scene that about helping a rival to their maximum potential before taking them down would work. The nearest scene I can think of is in the movie Achilles, when [Achilles doesn't attack Hector when he hits a stone, and waits for him to stand back](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQ62frK74u0). **However, it's just waiting for the opponent to heal themselves, not actively helping them reach their the best form and then argue/fight with this.**

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does the fight between Wesley and Enigo Montoya at the top of the cliffs in princess bride count? I can't confirm the points of your commentary from memory, but Enigo waits for Wesley to be fully recovered before they duel.

Comment: This question could be improved by adding *why* you want that information, because right now I see no option but to agree with a recommendation-based VTC.

Comment: It seems to me there's a little of that in the relationship between Eobard Thawne and Barry Allen, particularly in Season One of "The Flash".

Comment: @Joachim not sure what you mean. I want to illustrate the steelman concept, so I can write about it with an example. Does that answer you? I also have asked a [meta question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4687/46929) about this question

Comment: @KaiQing sound similar to the Achilles fight?

Comment: Umm, not necessarily by the description. That could be more like a professional courtesy. Like a UFC fighter allowing an opponent to stand back up instead of kicking them when they are down. In princess bride, Enigo and Wesley sit and talk while Wesley catches his strength after climbing a cliff face, which Enigo helped him climb just so they could duel. And Enigo even fights left handed because he sees himself as superior (at first). I don't know if it's unique, but it seems like a fairly close fit apart from it being a comedy.

Comment: The meta post you linked to has a bad example, since it is an example of a recommendation -- "I want to see X, what movie/TV show contains such a scene" -- and recommendations are off-topic as well. One could even regard this as some kind of identification question, which is also off-topic.

Comment: Saying that the meta post says your "question is allowed" seems like a stark misinterpretation of its somewhat incomplete answers.

Comment: About half the fights in DBZ/DB Super?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm not sure. The only answer I got back then was Glorfindel's. How could it be interpreted otherwise, if not "that's fine to ask such question"?

Answer (score 1):

### Aladdin (1992)

[image]

It might not fit the rules to a tee, but it does match the "making the opponent stronger" part of it. I'm referring to the 1992 movie, I can't speak to the more recent remake since I haven't seen it; though I assume the story is the same.

**Synopsis**

> Aladdin rubs the lamp and meets the Genie who lives inside it. The Genie grants Aladdin three wishes.
> [..]
> Aladdin breaks his promise and refuses to free the Genie. Iago steals the lamp, and Jafar becomes the Genie's new master. He uses his first two wishes to become Sultan and the world's most powerful sorcerer.
> [..]
> Aladdin taunts Jafar for being less powerful than the Genie, **tricking Jafar into using his last wish to become an all-powerful genie himself**. Now bound to his new lamp, Jafar ends up trapped inside it, taking Iago with him.

Aladdin egged Jafar on to become more powerful than the world's most powerful sorcerer (which he already was). That wasn't a lie, a genie is genuinely more powerful than a sorcerer (at least, the movie never contradicts this nor implies Aladdin was lying).